# General C++ Node class errors

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to implement the functionality of a stack and I was given the main.cpp file and was left to write the other files, namely StackofNodes.hpp & .h. These depend on two other files Node.hpp & .h. When I try to build the program I get the following errors

```
    ||=== Lab04, Debug ===|
/StackOfNodees.hpp||In member function ‘void StackOfNodees<T>::push(T)’:|
/StackOfNodees.hpp|30|error: expected type-specifier before ‘Node’|
/StackOfNodees.hpp|33|error: expected primary-expression before ‘value’|
/StackOfNodees.hpp|33|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘value’|
/StackOfNodees.hpp|38|error: expected initializer before ‘pop’|
/StackOfNodees.hpp||In instantiation of ‘void StackOfNodees<T>::push(T) [with T = int]’:|
/main.cpp|12|required from here|
/Node.h|10|error: ‘Node<int>* Node<int>::m_previous’ is private|
/StackOfNodees.hpp|31|error: within this context|
/Node.h|11|error: ‘int Node<int>::m_value’ is private|
/StackOfNodees.hpp|33|error: within this context|
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> //std::cout std::cin
#include "StackOfNodees.h" //StackOfNodes

int main()
{
    StackOfNodees<int> myStack; //Create an empty stack
    int sizeOfStack;    //int we'll use later to store the size of the stack

    //push some numbers onto the stack
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        myStack.push( i * 5 );
    }


    //Store the size of the stack before popping anything
    sizeOfStack = myStack.size();

    std::cout << "There are " << sizeOfStack << " items on the stack" << std::endl;

    //Think about why we don't use i<myStack.size()
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfStack; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Popping the top: " << myStack.pop() << std::endl;
    }

        /* while(!myStack.isEmpty()) is another valid way to pop all the contents of the stack */

}
```

StackOfNodees.hpp

```
    #ifndef STACKOFNODEES_HPP_INCLUDED
    #define STACKOFNODEES_HPP_INCLUDED

    template<typename T>
    StackOfNodees<T>::StackOfNodees()
    {
        m_top=nullptr;
        m_size=0;
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool StackOfNodees<T>::isEmpty() const
    {
        if (m_size==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    int StackOfNodees<T>::size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void StackOfNodees<T>::push(T)
    {
        Node<T>* Node1 = new Node;
        Node1 -> m_previous = m_top;
        m_top=Node1;
        Node1 -> m_value = T value;
        ++m_size;
    }

    template<typename T>
    int StackOfNodees<T>::T pop()
    {
        // initialize
        int returnval = 0;

        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            // fetch the value from the top one
            returnval = m_top -> m_value;

            Node* temp = m_top;

            //move m_top down to previous box.
            m_top = m_top -> m_previous;

            //delete the popped one
            delete temp;

            m_size--;
        }
        else
        {
            //may want to throw an exception here for popping a empty stack
        }

        return returnval;
    }




    #endif // STACKOFNODEES_HPP_INCLUDED


Node.h

   #ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED


template<typename T>

class Node
{
    private:
        Node<T>* m_previous;
        T m_value;

    public:
        Node();
        T getValue();
        Node<T>* getPrevious();

        void setValue(T value);
        void setPrevious(Node<T>* next);

};


#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

StackOfNodees.h

```
#ifndef STACKOFNODEES_H_INCLUDED
#define STACKOFNODEES_H_INCLUDED
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
class StackOfNodees
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_top;
    int m_size;

public:
    StackOfNodees();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push(T value);
    T pop();
};

#endif // STACKOFNODEES_H_INCLUDED
#include "StackOfNodees.hpp"
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED


template<typename T>

class Node
{
    private:
        Node<T>* m_previous;
        T m_value;

    public:
        Node();
        T getValue();
        Node<T>* getPrevious();

        void setValue(T value);
        void setPrevious(Node<T>* next);

};


#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to include `Node.h` in `StackOfNodees.h`.
2. Your template class' member function definitions must be inside the header file.
3. In your `pop()` method you're trying to use `m_previous` of the `Node` class, which is a private member. You need to either make the member public, add a public accessor function, or make the stack class a friend of the node class.
4. Same deal as #3 but with `m_value`.
5. The line `void StackOfNodees<T>::push(T)` should be `void StackOfNodees<T>::push(T value)`
6. Remove the `T` from the line `Node1 -> m_value = T value;`

These ought to clear up most if not all of those errors.

Comment: Could you take a look at the `StackOfNodees.h` that I added to the question? Should I add what @Claptrap mentioned to it? If so where?

Comment: Yes, you also need to add your method definitions to the header file. With templates, the definitions have to be in the header.

Comment: Ok so in my `Node.h` I have `getPrevious` which I could use as a `public accesor` for `m_previous`

Comment: @rubito yes and you also need an accessor for setting `m_value` since that is also private.

Comment: For that I have `T getValue();` as public. And I used that and it cleared up most of the errors. Now I'm only left with "error: expected type-specifier before 'Node'" and "StackOfNodees.hpp|39|error: expected initializer before ‘pop’|". Also, it says that `Node1 -> getPrevious() = m_top;' needs a left operand of assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
void StackOfNodees<T>::push(T)
{
    Node<T>* Node1 = new Node;
    Node1 -> m_previous = m_top;
    m_top=Node1;
    Node1 -> m_value = T value;
    ++m_size;
}
```

There might be multiple reasons for this.

- Compiler is not able to find Node class, make sure you #include the header that defines it.

  ```
  Node1 -> m_value = T value;
  ```

what is the above line doing there, You must define variable before you use.In C++ , you cannot define and use varibale in same statement.Use is as below

```
    Node1 -> m_value = value;
```